# Ruby - Find first and last names in text from email address

Tags: ruby, regex

This is an interesting issue I have been playing around with but unable to find an answer for.

I have a text file of unstructured data that includes emails as well as full names. I already have the emails extracted but I want to map first and last names to each email as well.

So suppose the email is ksmith@gmail.com, and somewhere on the page is 'Kevin Smith'.

I'd want to use whatever is in front of '@' to map the full name from somewhere in the text. But obviously searching for 'ksmith' will return no match. So then, starting from the left, I'd search for one less character, ie 'smith', which would match.

But then when I find 'Smith', I also want to find the first name. so maybe assume this will always be the last name (since most emails have last but not first names) and search to the left from 'Smith' until reaching the next space (in front of 'Kevin') and figuring that what is between the space before 'Smith' and before 'Kevin' is the first name.

But then, what if the full name is "Kevin Michael Smith" or "Kevin P. Smith"? In which case I don't want "Michael" or "P.", but Kevin as the first name.

Or what if the email structure is smithk@gmail.com, in which case shrinking the substring from the left will never be a match and I'd need to try from the other side as well.

Basically I need a method smart enough to recognize these full names in a number of cases.

Any help would be appreciated!

I am trying to do this in Ruby, if that helps

Comment: "M. Kevin Smith" is another variant to consider--people who go by their middle names, or "J.P. Smith", or "The Hon. J. Michael Smith III". And we must not forget "Cher". I'm guessing this type of problem is encountered often.

Comment: So you basically want us to fix the cases where your vaguely specified heuristic fails, and code it for you? Thanks, maybe some other time. Write actual code and perhaps then ask again.

Comment: Don't expect anyone to code this for me, I am just trying to understand how to best approach this. From Cary's comment, I see I have not considered all the relevant issues and wanted to get feedback on how to tackle a problem like this, and if it is even possible to do reliably with code. Sorry if the question offended you...

Comment: So - what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

When you find the last name, you move back to the first name so instead of moving left of 'Smith' until reaching the **next space**, you should see if there is space behind the first alphabet of next name for example your algorithm for "Kevin P. Smith" will find "P." but if you check if there is space behind "P" then find next part of the name. So for "Kevin Micheal John Smith" you will get Kevin because first you reach "John" then you see there is space behind "J" so you move back to "Micheal" again there is space bind "M" so you move to "Kevin". As there is no space behind Kevin so you have the first name.

Easiest solution is to use the Split function for example

```
string_=string_.split(" ");
firstName=string_[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to write an algorithm, which make an array of full name. for exmple :

```
a = ["kevin smit", "andrew john", "thom devid", "M. K. Add","k smith"]
b= "ksmith@gmail.com"
c = b.split('@')[0]
=> "ksmith" 
first = c[0]
=> "k"
last = c[1..c.length]
=> "smith" 

a.each do |i|
  if i.gsub(" ").count == 1
    if (i.split(" ")[0][0] == first && i.split(" ")[1] == last) ||   (i.split(" ")[0][0] == last && i.split(" ")[1] == first)
       p i
    end
  elsif i.gsub(" ").count == 2
    if (i.split(" ")[0][0] == first && i.split(" ")[2] == last) ||   (i.split(" ")[0][0] == last && i.split(" ")[2] == first)
       p i.split(" ")[0] +  i.split(" ")[2]
    end
  end
end
```

This will works for you. And you can use switch-case insted of if-else if there are multiple scenarios